# Why is this closed as "off-topic"?

Tags: support, closed-questions

This question is totally on-topic — it is directly linked to a tag which has hundreds of questions ([domain-driven-design](/questions/tagged/domain-driven-design)):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612860/domaindrivendesign-org-where-has-it-gone

It has been closed as "off-topic" though.

An answer has been provided, but for sure, some people in the world could have a more precise answer (for example, when the reference web site will be re-opened).

**EDIT 1** : There was indeed a more precise answer, it can be found here :

[Where is the reference community web site about Domain-Driven Design ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660924/where-is-the-reference-community-web-site-about-domain-driven-design)

Anyone can copy my answer to the answer field, and I will accept it...

**EDIT 2** : It looks like a few of you downvote this information, but many upvote it : https://stackoverflow.com/users/668455/tristan?tab=reputation#reppage_1-repview_post

I think this question should be re-opened, or the first one should be undeleted, re-opened, and answered.

I was only trying to correct all the duplicate wrong links in one shared place, instead of correcting them in many places. In programming language, this is called "factoring", and it's a good practice, as you may know.

Comment: Would it be on-topic on programmers SE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I sympathize and agree this is an edge case: Like the linked duplicate, it is about a broken URL that is relevant to programming, and understanding some SO answers.

The community's stance on this seems pretty clear however: Yours and the duplicate question got both closed as off-topic. I'll cast a reopen vote on the dupe, but I don't think it's going to work out.

I guess the best you can do is wait and see whether the site goes online again.

Comment: Thanks Pekka. Sure, I can wait for the site to go online again, but it may have been migrated elsewhere.

Comment: By the way, people who have voted to close my question don't know what domain-driven design is : they don't have this tag in their interests.

Comment: ­@ Tristan: I don't have this tag in my intererests on my SO account, but I know what DDD is. I have worked with it in the past. Your making a broad assumption with your last statement.

Comment: Why is a site down isn't related to programming IMO, even if the site is about programming or development.

Comment: @bleakcabal mmm, I'd tend to give it some leeway if it's about a programming resource. It *is* somewhat pertinent to the field of programming whether an on-line manual is available or where it has gone.

Comment: Personally, I consider the question Too Localized.

Comment: @R.Bemrose I don't think I would. Imagine if it weren't DDD related, but the PHP or jQuery docs. SO would be abuzz with questions, and you can bet they would be let live.

Comment: @Pekka: I was referring more to the "specific point in time" phrasing, but since you brought it up, Domain Driven Design is a concept, not a language or library, and as such does not have any official docs, let alone an official site.

Comment: @R.Bemrose the site seems to be linked as a quasi-standard source in several SO answers, though. But fair enough, you have a point

Comment: I try to understand your point of view, but I don't. If I go to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery#References and I click the first link, and it points to nowhere, I can ask about it on SO, but if I go to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design#References and I click the first link, and it points to nowhere, it's off-topic to ask about it on SO ? Is there a war between "programmers" and "designers" on SO ?

Comment: @Tristan: I disagree with Pekka here. I don't think questions about jquery.com would be on topic either.

Comment: @mmyers you are probably right, but if the jQuery docs (or CDN) were down, I'd bet large sums of money that the question would stay open. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473976/can-anyone-access-the-jquery-tools-from-cdn

Answer (score 12):

```
Questions on Stack Overflow are expected to generally relate to 
programming or software development in some way, 
within the scope defined in the faq.
```

Your question was asking for a URL. While the URL may be programming related the question wasn't and was deemed off topic. You don't have enough rep to comment yet but when you do I would suggest commenting on an answer if there is a URL with a problem rather than posting a question. I'm not one of the closers so they may give a better answer, but that it is why I suspect that it was closed.

Comment: Well, I understand your answer, but my question is about a big piece of knowledge which seems to have disappeared from the internet, not just "about an URL", and it has been voted up a few times.So I hope my question will be re-opened soon since it is directly related to software development

Comment: So, let's make a summary : my question is about an URL and this URL is about software development, what's your way to conclude my question is not about software development ?

Comment: It's not directly about software development. Yes, it is a useful website but the question you asked wasn't related to software development. At best it could be considered about a tool used by developers, but obviously that wasn't the opinion of the close voters.

Comment: Ok, I give up, you're right, let's delete the 1117 tagged questions about domain-driven-design because they're off-topic : design practices are not a tool for developers because a few people of the SO community think so. Let's all maintain "big ball of mud" just as Bill the Lizard does.

Comment: Design practices are a tool. URL's about design practices are not.

Comment: Ok, I withdraw my proposition : let's keep the 1117 questions about domain-driven-design, but let's remove all URLs from the answers, because they are "off-topic".

Comment: *sigh* An answer that links to a URL for more information is on topic as long as the URL isn't the whole answer and the post does answer the question i.e. you can reference a website in an answer but not ask a question about where a website has gone.

Comment: Well, maybe you could write to someone to add your own rules in the FAQ, but for now, they are not mentionned.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet would have been to email the team about it (team@stackoverflow.com), or flag one of your other questions for a moderator and pointed them to the original question, and ask them to undelete or re-open it (if it really was on topic).

However, what you did was:

- [Ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612860/domaindrivendesign-org-where-has-it-gone).
- It gets [closed as off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5612860/revisions).
- [You ask about it here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87067/why-is-this-closed-as-off-topic).
- It gets deleted.
- Then [you ask the question *again*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660924/where-is-the-reference-community-web-site-about-domain-driven-design).

That last part is generally not accepted on Stack Overflow.  **Don't** re-ask a question again just because your first was closed or deleted.

**Update**: The [re-asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660924/where-is-the-reference-community-web-site-about-domain-driven-design) has been closed by a moderator as `off-topic`.  I would have voted to close it as off topic [for reasons that others have given](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87067/why-is-this-closed-as-off-topic/87070#87070).

Comment: Ok, why not, I'm quite new to SO, I'm still learning... What you may not know is that I asked about my question here *before* it was deleted. I didn't know about this "undelete" feature, but what if my question gets "undelete" and deleted again ?

Comment: Yes, you did ask about it here before you deleted it. I saw the timestamps (I'll update my answer to reflect the correct timeline of events).  It was asked here, and it didn't garner enough votes to re-open it.  So, the community has spoken. It was then deleted. To be undeleted, it needs 3 votes, and it needs another 5 to be re-opened. If it's deleted again, then it's probably a safe bet that your question (however interesting to you) does not belong on Stack Overflow as a 'programming' question.

Comment: Ok, how can someone vote to undelete a deleted question ? Where can they be found (the deleted questions) ?

Comment: @Tristan If you have 10K reputation (or are a Moderator) you can see deleted questions. They reside at their original URLs.  Anyone over 10K can vote to undelete a deleted question.